# Fop migration from 0.20.5 to 2.9

Tags: apache-fop

Right now I'm on it to migrate a old application based on fop 0.20.5 to 2.9.
It contains several self written extensions, which I want to rewrite.
Here I stuck currently on the point that I can't find a replacement for the following function:

```
public class PdfInclude extends FObj {
...

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int layout(Area area) throws FOPException {
...

area.getPage().getFormattedNumber();

...
}
}
```

it gives you the current page number back and I need it for some further steps.

I tried it for example with:

```
<xsl:attribute name="destinationPage">
    <fo:page-number/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

-> Line #34; Column #23; fo:page-number is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!

If somebody has a solution for my problem, I would be very happy.

I tried it for example with:

```
<xsl:attribute name="destinationPage">
    <fo:page-number/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

-> Line #34; Column #23; fo:page-number is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!

If somebody has a solution for my problem, I would be very happy.